# How to use eclipse and cvs commit and update

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I and my team are located in different places, we hope to share our timely written procedures, so we decided to use eclipse + cvs, but we don't know that it can not be on a different LAN updating and submitting our program.Who can give you some suggestions to us

Comment: CVS is very much outdated. I would suggest using something newer, like subversion(SVN) or git.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can we achieve it with cvs?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used CVS in Eclipse for some time, but it should be quite simple. Use the context menu->Team->Share project, select CVS and enter the details of your cvs server. Or use the cvs repository view to check out from your cvs repository.

You have to make sure first, that everyone on the team can access the central cvs repository, of course, e.g. via SSH.

For more details I would suggest looking for a tutorial on google.